# How do I write a GCS function to stop my project once budget is reached?

Tags: google-cloud-functions

I'm building a website using Google Cloud Services. Currently trying to put in fail-safes to stop all services once budget reaches a certain point.

It seems like the best way to do this is by making budget alerts, then writing a GC function that stops API permissions for the project?

I am currently have trouble writing the GC function that stops API permissions for the project. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "I am currently have trouble writing the GC function that stops API permissions for the project" -> Please edit your question to show what you tried already. Without that, this comes down to a request for us to write code for you - which is not what Stack Overflow is about.

Comment: The code to cancel the billing for a proejct is pretty much verbatim included in this documentation page: https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/notify#write-a-cloud-function-2. If you're having trouble making that work, edit your question to include the code that shows where you got stuck.

Comment: How do you measure "budget reaches a certain point"? Over a period (e.g. week, month, etc...)? Do you plan to start the services again after it had been shut down? Anyways, I'd look into unlinking the billing account instead of disabling all resources in the project.